# Is there a function for finding the furthest data point from a linear line of best fit scatter graph

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scatter-plot

Trying to find the furthest data point from linear line of best fit so can use as initial guess for an additional gaussian fit. Need furthest data point as can then use that as a rough mean guess for optimization. Require x value of data point. 
    def fit_func(x,a,mu,sig,m,c):               #function for gaussian and linear fit
    gaus = a*sp.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2)) 
    line = m*x+c 
    return gaus + line
def maximise(x,y,m,c):
    distance=(sp.sqrt(x**2+y**2)-sp.sqrt(x**2+((m*x+c)**2)))
    max_xval=[sp.argmax(distance)]
    return max_xval 
    for f in A:
    with open(f,'r') as file:
        line1=file.readline()
        line1_split=line1.split(',')
        if 'Instrument Response: Good ' in line1_split[3]:          #filtering good data from bad
            print(f)
            print(line1_split[3])
            #good_file_data.append(f)
            J,Z=sp.loadtxt(f,delimiter=',', skiprows=2,unpack=True)   #reading good data
            plt.plot(J,Z)
            maximise(J,Z,(Z[999]-Z[0])/(J[999]-J[0]),50)
            initial_guess=[30,maximise,1,(Z[999]-Z[0])/(J[999]-J[0]),50]
            po,po_cov=sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func,J,Z,initial_guess, maxfev=2000000000)      #plotting line of best fit and scatter graph
            plt.plot(J,fit_func(J,po[0],po[1],po[2],po[3],po[4]))
            plt.plot(sp.unique(J), sp.poly1d(sp.polyfit(J, Z, 1))(sp.unique(J)))
            K=[J,Z]
            plt.xlabel('Wavelength/nm')
            plt.ylabel('Intensity/AU')
            plt.show()
Get back a type error of float and function as maximise isn't returning a value.

Comment: Using a [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) you can project all your points  onto your best-fit line using linear algebra (which should be quick in a python implementation since it's just matrix/vector manipulation. Then you can define the distance for each point as the magnitude of the vector that you get when you subtract the two vectors of a point (pre/post projection). See the definition of `a_2` in my link

Comment: have done but hasn't formatted as code, sorry. Quite new to SO

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume both xvals, yvals, and yfit are all arrays. Assuming i'm not missing something here you could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# create an array of delta values
delta_fit = abs(yvals - yfit)

# find the index where the maximum delta point is located
max_idx = np.argmax(delta_fit)

# get the xvals value at max_idx
max_xval = xvals[max_idx]
```

This assumes your arrays have the same shape and you are interested in determining the max distance from the fit for a given index location.